# Azure AD B2C Single Sign Out not signing out all applications when using multiple protocols

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We have circa 50 applications that integrate with Azure AD B2C, which comprises a mix of OpenId Connect relying parties and Saml2 service providers.

The custom policies we have built have been configured to support Single Sign Out (based on the following document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#single-sign-out).

We see the following behaviours:

- When initiating sign-out from an OpenId Connect RP all other OpenId Connect RPs that the user is signed into are signed out, BUT no Saml SPs that the user is signed into are signed out.
- When initiating sign-out from a Saml2 SP all other Saml2 SPs that the user is signed into are signed out, BUT no OpenId Connect RPs that the user is signed into are signed out.

It appears that Single Sign Out is not working across protocols in B2C - is this correct or could we have an issue in our custom policy implementation?  Given different session management providers are used for each protocol does that suggest the former?

Comment: It should work across protocols, as long as the SM is setup as per that Doc in each B2C Policy you have. Would raise a MS support ticket if it is not.

Comment: Hi @JasSuri-MSFT many thanks for your response.  I have taken another look at our policies and after making some tweaks we now have it working.

To make policy management a bit easier we have two separate branches on top of TrustFrameworkExtensions - one with Oidc-specific extensions (technical profiles, user journeys, etc) and one with the equivalents for Saml2.  It seems that when the session management technical profiles are in separate parts of the tree Single Sign Out doesn't work across both protocols but if we move them all into TrustFrameworkExtensions then all works as expected.